# React Three Fiber animating elements in an array in sequence

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm pretty green with React Three Fiber but I'm trying to make a bin packing UI where the individual boxes drop down into the packing box.  The inside boxes are in an array that is being mapped.  The below is really rough code as I'm still experimenting.  But at the moment all the boxes are dropping at the same time.  I want them to drop one at a time. Any ideas on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

```
export const BinPacker = () => {
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);

  // test item coordinates
  const positions = useMemo(() => [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0.65, -0.05, 0],
    [0.65, -0.1, 0.55],
    [0.2, -0.15, 0.65],
    [-0.3, -0.2, 0.6],
    // [1, 0, 1.1],
    // [0, 1, 0],

  ], []);
  // test item dimensions
  const packages = useMemo(() => [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0.3, 0.9, 0.6],
    [0.3, 0.8, 0.5],
    [0.6, 0.7, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.6, 0.2],
    // [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
    // [0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
  ], []);
  const positionsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(positions));
  const startingPositions = positionsCopy.map(pos => [pos[0], pos[1] += 3, pos[2]]);
  const [startPosition, setStartPosition] = useState(startingPositions);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setStartPosition(startingPositions);
    setAnimate(true);
  }, [startingPositions]);


  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </Button>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [3, 3, 3], fov: 50 }}>
        <PackingBox position={[0, 0.2, 0]} />
        {positions.map((pos, index) => {
          return (
            <ItemBoxes key={pos} animate={animate} position={pos} setAnimate={setAnimate} setStartPosition={setStartPosition} size={packages[index]}startingPosition={startPosition[index]} />
          );
        })}
        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </>

  );
};
```

And the item component is -

```
export const ItemBoxes = ({
  position, animate, startingPosition, setAnimate, setStartPosition, size
}) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useFrame((_, delta) => {
    if (animate) {
      if (ref.current.position.y > position[1]) {
        ref.current.position.y -= 1 * delta;
      }
      if (ref.current.position.y <= position[1]) {
        setAnimate(false);
      }
    }
  });


  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={startingPosition}>
      <boxGeometry args={size} attach='geometry' />
      <meshBasicMaterial attach='material-0' color='#ff99ff' opacity={0.6} transparent />
      <meshBasicMaterial attach='material-2' color='#99ccff' opacity={0.6} transparent />
      <meshBasicMaterial attach='material-4' color='#ff6699' opacity={0.6} transparent />
      <Edges
        color='grey'
        scale={1}
        threshold={15} // Display edges only when the angle between two faces exceeds this value (default=15 degrees)
      />
    </mesh>);
};
```